# SQL Server 2012 Invalid Column Name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, intellisense

Does anybody know why SQL Server 2012 shows these as invalid column names even though I know they are valid and the query executes successfully? Intellisense also doesn't show me the column names as I type them out either.

[image]

Comment: Press CTRL+SHIFT+R to refresh intellisense cache

Comment: Try refreshing the intellisense cache with CTRL+SHIFT+R

Comment: It does that all the time.  It's usually because the view you have open there is likely not looking at the database you opened the query from.  Like, the window is looking at "master", but all the tables are in "someOtherDB".  In most cases, the query will run anyway.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your cache?  CTRL + SHIFT + R?

Comment: Thanks! CTRL+SHIFT+R did the trick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press CTRL+SHIFT+R to refresh intellisense cache